# Setting resources dynamically on snakemake

Tags: snakemake

**Context**
I am running a snakemake pipeline using slurm task manager. I have set resources (time and memory for each rule) dynamically based on file size and # of tries, like this:

```
rule index:
    resources:
        mem_mb = lambda wildcards, input, attempt: (
            200 * attempt
        ),
        runtime = lambda wildcards, input, attempt: (
            "{minutes}min".format(
                minutes=max(
                    int((input.size_mb / 5000) * attempt),
                    1)
            )
        )
```

I have 2 related questions (should I split the post?):
**1) Is it possible to set resources dinamically outside of snakefile?**
I tried to set that on the profile config file but didn't success (sometime ago, so cannot say exactly what I tried)

**2) Having set resources dinamically inside Snakefile, how do I do a dry run or a rulegraph**?
If I run a dry-run I get the following error:

```
WorkflowError:
Cannot parse runtime value into minutes for setting runtime resource: <TBD>
```

This seems logical to me since the file doesn't exist yet. Nevertheless, I would like to know the specifics of all steps (except resources of course) to be run before actually running them, is this possible?
Something similar happens if I try to do a rulegraph:

```
snakemake --profile Config/Profiles/slurm -np --rulegraph | dot -Tsvg > rulegraph.svg
```

In this case, I get an empty file (probably because of the error in the dry run?).